# Live Look Template

Tags: templates

This is probably really simple - but I can't find the answer...

We have set up a "Live Look Template" so that editors can preview an entry.

**QUESTION**

*When an editor is logged in to the backend - Is there a way we can make the link going to this Live Look Template open in a new window?*

I have circled the link I'm talking about...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the add-on Zenbu will open the live-look previews in a lightbox style modal if you wanted to use that. It's pretty good and gives you the ability to create custom views for entry lists.

However, you could create an accessory which hooked into the live-look links and used Javascript to open them in a new window. The difficulty is in hooking into the links since they don't have any kind of class on them.

You could look for the word "View" in a link or count which column the link is in and target that. Neither way is going to be bulletproof but it might work for your circumstances.

**UPDATE:** Just made an accessory for you. [Download accessory to open Live Look links in a new window](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/live-look-in-new-window) Unzip it into your expressionengine/third_party folder and install it from Add-ons->Accessories. This just looks for links with the word "View" so it's far from robust but it should do the job in a basic way.

Comment: +1 for the accessory and +1 for Zenbu.

Comment: Wow - that is so kind of you to make this. We have tested the accessory and it works great. In this scenario it is perfect for what we are doing. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem. I've actually just updated the accessory so it hides the unnecessary tab at the bottom of the CP.

Comment: Just updated the accessory and it's working great (and no tab). I owe you a beer. Thanks again!